# How popular is the idea of building a nuclear power plant in Egypt?

Tags: public-opinion, nuclear-energy, egypt

It just crossed my news feed that [Egyptian President el-Sisi finalized the deal with Putin](https://www.voanews.com/a/egypt-finalizes-deal-with-russia-for-first-nuclear-plant/4014549.html) to build [Egypt's first nuclear power plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Dabaa_Nuclear_Power_Plant).

In the last several years, there was a notable drop (e.g. [in USA](http://news.gallup.com/poll/190064/first-time-majority-oppose-nuclear-energy.aspx)) in the popularity of nuclear energy among Western populace (shutting down of plants in Europe), probably at least partially influenced by Fukushima incident *[citation needed]*.

In light of such dropping popularity of nuclear energy in the Western countries, ***how popular is the idea of building a nuclear power plant among population of Egypt?*** Did that change in ways correllated to western public opinion?

Comment: There was a global survey done in 2011.   Egypt came in at 31% in favor, which was noted as "high" for a nation that currently didn't have Nuclear power.    http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-15864806 and https://www.globescan.com/news-and-analysis/press-releases/press-releases-2011/94-press-releases-2011/127-opposition-to-nuclear-energy-grows-global-poll.html

Comment: @userLTK that looks like the core to a good answer.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I felt it was too limited.  Its just one dataset from a survey/poll 6 years ago.  If it was after the Egypt-Russia announcement I might have made it an answer.